# How many array types are in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I wish I can create a function that will help me to get the last item from an array, NOT just from a normal array, but from other array types such as NodeList, (the only two types I know are NodeLists and Arrays)

my function:

```
       const getLastItem = (list) => {
            if (list instanceof Array || OR NODELIST OR ANYTHING ELSE) {
                return list.slice(-1)[0];
            }
            if(typeof list == 'object'){
           // get the last key from an object, it's another thing which I wish to append to this
           // function
              return Object.keys(list).slice(-1)[0]
           //this will return the last key from an object
            }
        }
```

[EDIT]: and do you think that there is a better implementation than this one?

Comment: ```function isIterable(obj) {
  return typeof obj[Symbol.iterator] === 'function';
}```

Comment: Does "last key from an Object" actually make sense? Is there a defined order that would mean that "last" had any useful meaning?

Comment: @ritaj, sorry, could you please explain?

Comment: @SpoonMeiser .................. object items are not order guaranteed in javascript ????

Comment: I would experiment with `Array.prototype.slice.apply`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#:~:text=The%20iterable%20protocol%20allows%20JavaScript,such%20as%20Object%20)%20are%20not.

Comment: First convert your iterable to an array then return the last element.

Comment: @pishpish, good Idea, that's better implementation, yes, thank you very much

Comment: And I'd recommend `array[array.length - 1]` instead of `.slice`ing.

Comment: @pishpish, why? I've been using array[array.length - 1] for a long time, but I've found that using slicing will make your code shorter

Comment: I guess it shouldn't make any real difference, but I try to avoid additional function calls when possible. Too bad JS never got `[-1]` syntax.

Comment: This question's title has nothing to do with the question. Also, "better" is in the eye of the beholder, unless there are specific objective measurable aspects you want to improve.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this? The function grabs the last item from iterables and calls itself recursively on `Object.entries` of non-iterable objects. It returns `undefined` if it can't do either (or if the iterable is empty).

```js
const getLastItem = obj => {
    if (obj && obj[Symbol.iterator]) {
        const arr = [...obj]

        return arr[arr.length - 1]
    } else if (obj && typeof obj === 'object') {
        // You could also use `Object.keys` or `Object.values`
        // depending what you want to happen.
        // Note that relying on the order of properties
        // in normal objects is typically a bad idea.
        return getLastItem(Object.entries(obj))
    }
    
    return undefined
}

;[
    // all of the following work
    getLastItem([1, 2]),
    getLastItem({a: 1, b: 2}),
    getLastItem(document.querySelectorAll('p')),
    getLastItem(new Set([1, 2])),
    getLastItem(new Map([['a', 1], ['b', 2]])),
    getLastItem(document.querySelector('p').classList),
    getLastItem('string!'),
    
    // all of the following are `undefined`
    getLastItem(null),
    getLastItem(undefined),
    getLastItem(0),
    getLastItem(1),
    getLastItem(document.querySelectorAll('fake-element')),
    getLastItem([]),
    getLastItem({}),
    getLastItem(''),
    getLastItem(new WeakMap([[{}, 1], [{}, 2]])), // not iterable
].forEach(x => console.log(x))

// Edge case: if `obj` is an infinite iterable, you'll get
// stuck in an infinite loop due to use of the spread operator...
// So don't do this 
// 
// const infiniteIterable = (n => ({
//     *[Symbol.iterator] () {
//         while(true) yield n++
//     },
// }))(0)
// 
// getLastItem(infiniteIterable)
```

```html
<p class="class1 class2 class3">first</p>

<p>second</p>

<p>last</p>
```